# I want to create checkbox checked in nested data in react js

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

My data is in nested array objects. I want to make checked/unchecked the nodes like a tree view. ie. when any child node is selected then the parent node is checked itself.
[image: This is how my nested array looks like.]

This is my nested JSON. From this object, I create a tree view from this data:

[image: My tree structure]

```
 const nodes = [
  {
    value: "/app",
    label: "app",
    children: [
      {
        value: "/app/Http",
        label: "Http",
        children: [
          {
            value: "/app/Http/Controllers",
            label: "Controllers",
            children: [
              {
                value: "/app/Http/Controllers/WelcomeController.js",
                label: "WelcomeController.js",
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            value: "/app/Http/routes.js",
            label: "routes.js",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        value: "/app/Providers",
        label: "Providers",
        children: [
          {
            value: "/app/Http/Providers/EventServiceProvider.js",
            label: "EventServiceProvider.js",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    value: "/config",
    label: "config",
    children: [
      {
        value: "/config/app.js",
        label: "app.js",
      },
      {
        value: "/config/database.js",
        label: "database.js",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    value: "/public",
    label: "public",
    children: [
      {
        value: "/public/assets/",
        label: "assets",
        children: [
          {
            value: "/public/assets/style.css",
            label: "style.css",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        value: "/public/index.html",
        label: "index.html",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    value: "/.env",
    label: ".env",
  },
  {
    value: "/.gitignore",
    label: ".gitignore",
  },
  {
    value: "/README.md",
    label: "README.md",
  },
];
```

I am using this function to make parent checked when child is checked.

```
checkChange(targetNode: any, event) {
    /// debugger;
    const targetNodeId = targetNode.id;
    this.findIndexNestedforCheckbox(targetNode, targetNodeId);
    let newTableData = [...this.state.tableData];
    this.setState({ tableData: newTableData, isActionFooter: true });
  }
findIndexNestedforCheckbox(data, index) {
   
    if (data.id === index) data.isChecked = "Yes";

    let result;
    const i = (data.children || []).findIndex((child) => {
      child.isChecked = "Yes";

      return (result = this.findIndexNestedforCheckbox(child, index));
    });
    if (result) return [i, ...result];
  }
```

Comment: I think you should clarify what's the problem with your current solution or what is missing out.
With quick read your question reads like "I want to do X and this is how I solved the problem."

Comment: I'd say it is controversial approach from UX standpoint - if you got parent node checked, you would normally expect ***all*** of its children to be checked. For your use case, I would say something, like *half-checked* checkboxes would suit better.

Comment: Back to your particular case, does it mean that parents all the way to the top should get checked? E.g. when `'"WelcomeController.js"` is clicked, does it get `"Controllers"`, `"Http"` and `"App"` checked?

Comment: ...if yes standard is to include intermediate mode in your logic.
https://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/

Answer (score 0):

**npm install react-checkbox-tree**

```
import React from 'react';
import CheckboxTree from 'react-checkbox-tree';

const nodes = [{
    value: 'mars',
    label: 'Mars',
    children: [
        { value: 'phobos', label: 'Phobos' },
        { value: 'deimos', label: 'Deimos' },
    ],
}];

class Widget extends React.Component {
    state = {
        checked: [],
        expanded: [],
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <CheckboxTree
                nodes={nodes}
                checked={this.state.checked}
                expanded={this.state.expanded}
                onCheck={checked => this.setState({ checked })}
                onExpand={expanded => this.setState({ expanded })}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).